# Accessing WebDriver from async delegate prevents future FindElements

Tags: .net, multithreading, selenium, asynchronous, timer

When I invoke an `Action` asynchronously and interact with the WebDriver I can no longer use it to find elements:

```
    public void AsyncWebDriver()
    {
        var homePage = new Uri("http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html");

        var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(INTERNET_EXPLORER_OPTIONS);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homePage);


        Action bar = () => Console.WriteLine(driver.Url);

        bar.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var foo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("showtoast"));
            foo.Click();
        }
    }
```

This fails, but if we either comment out the delegate or invoke it synchronously (i.e. `bar()`) when I can click as expected.

When the test does fail I can see that the returned value the `FindElement` is odd.

When the test passes, the `tagname` and `text` properties are set as expected:

```
TagName = "button"
Text = "Show Toast"
```

However, when it fails it will alternate between returning `null` and returning an `IWebElement`  with the `text` and `tag` properties as so:

```
TagName = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
Text = "button"
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is **not** thread-safe.  In fact, it's so not thread-safe that it goes mad if you do anything thread-ish.

The fix is to `lock` the calls as so:

```
[Test]
public void AsyncWebDriver()
{
    var o = new object();

    var homePage = new Uri("http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html");

    var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(INTERNET_EXPLORER_OPTIONS);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homePage);

    Action bar = () =>
                    {
                        lock (o)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(driver.Url);
                        }
                    };

    bar.BeginInvoke(null, null);


    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            var foo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("showtoast"));
            foo.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Once the access to the driver is synchronised with the `lock` statement everything works we expected.